# Problem using QuerydslBinderCustomizer and @QueryInit at the same time

Tags: java, spring, querydsl

Giving the following classes

```
public class Department {
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idDepartment")
    @QueryInit("customer.company")
    private Project project;
    ...
}

public class Project {
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idCustomer")
    private Customer customer;
    ...
}

public class Customer {
    ...

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idCompany")
    private Company company;
    ...
}
```

**I need to use `@QueryInit` on `project` to be able to access the 4th level or more, like this:**

```
predicate.and(
    QDepartment.department.project.customer.company.id.eq(idCompany)
);
```

**At the same time, I need to use `QuerydslBinderCustomizer` so I can customize the filter behavior**

```
public interface DepartmentRepository
        extends CrudRepository<Department, UUID>, 
        PagingAndSortingRepository<Department, UUID>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Department>, 
        QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QDepartment> {

    @Override
    default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QDepartment root) {
        bindings.bind(root.version).first((path, value) -> path.goe(value));
        bindings.bind(String.class).first((StringPath path, String value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
    }
}
```

**When I use the `@QueryInit`, the `customize` is not called and my customization doesn't work**

I've already tried to update the the last `Querydsl` version 4.4.0 and add the `com.mysema.querydsl` `querydsl-apt` but does not work anyway

---

Currently I'm using the predicate on service level, like this

```
public Page<Department> list(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable){
   BooleanBuilder predicateDepartment = new BooleanBuilder(predicate);
        UUID idCompany = 
   springUserDetailsService.getUserSpring().getIdCompany();

   predicateDepartment.and(
       QDepartment.department.project.customer.company.id.eq(idCompany)
   );

   return repository.findAll(predicateDepartment, pageable);
}
```

So I think I can't configure the `EntityPath` inside the `customize()`, because it's called when the repository is called

---

The solution applyed to my code:

```
public Page<Department> list(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable){
   BooleanBuilder predicateDepartment = new BooleanBuilder(predicate);
        UUID idCompany = 
   springUserDetailsService.getUserSpring().getIdCompany();

---change---
   QDepartment initalizedRoot = new QDepartment(QDepartment.department.getMetadata(),
                PathInits.getFor(QDepartment.department.getMetadata(), new PathInits("*.*", "project.customer.company")));
---end change---
   predicateDepartment.and(
       QDepartment.department.project.customer.company.id.eq(idCompany)
   );

   return repository.findAll(predicateDepartment, pageable);
}
```

----**Update 10/16/2020**----

I'm facing a weird behavior now.
After many tests I was able to make everything works right without using the `PathInits` configuration on my service, only using the `@QueryInit` in my Entity and the `customize()` in my Repository...

I thought the lib update was responsible to correct the situation.
But after compiling and running a couple of times (changing other things but this config), the `customize()` has not been called anymore.
The `list()` method is called without trigger the `customize()`.

So.. I made a simple insert of the `PathInit` config code in my service and now the `customize()` has been called again.

The code was this, and the `customize()` is not called on repository

```
public Page<Department> list(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable){
   BooleanBuilder predicateDepartment = new BooleanBuilder(predicate);
        UUID idCompany = 
   springUserDetailsService.getUserSpring().getIdCompany();
   predicateDepartment.and(
       QDepartment.department.project.customer.company.id.eq(idCompany)
   );

   return repository.findAll(predicateDepartment, pageable);
}
```

So I changed to this, and now the `customize()` is called on repository:

```
public Page<Department> list(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable){
   BooleanBuilder predicateDepartment = new BooleanBuilder(predicate);
        UUID idCompany = 
   springUserDetailsService.getUserSpring().getIdCompany();

   QDepartment qTest = new QDepartment(QDepartment.department.getMetadata(), PathInits.DIRECT2);

   predicateDepartment.and(
       QDepartment.department.project.customer.company.id.eq(idCompany)
   );

   return repository.findAll(predicateDepartment, pageable);
}
```

The `qTest` variable is initialized but is not used anywhere, but its affecting the behavior even so.
It looks like the `new QDepartment(...)` is the key to force the `customize()` to be called.

--- Another update, more info ---

The code above works only if I'm on debug mode.

--- Final solution ---

All I had to do to solve this problem is to put the binding to the Repository `bindings = DepartmentRepository.class` on my Controller.

```
public Page<Department> list(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Department.class, bindings = DepartmentRepository.class) Predicate predicate,
                                 @PageableDefault Pageable pageable) {
    return service.list(predicate, pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution here
https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-querydsl-sd-demo

To have the customize to work you need to bind the controller Predicate to the Repository

`bindings = DepartmentRepository.class`

```
@GetMapping
@ResponseBody
public Page<Department> list(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Department.class, bindings = DepartmentRepository.class) Predicate predicate,
                             @PageableDefault Pageable pageable) {
    return service.list(predicate, pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably `spring-data` ignores the default QueryInits declared in the QueryDSL static metamodel. Nothing prevents you from wrapping an EntityPath expression in another EntityPath expression with more initialized paths:

```java
default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QDepartment root) {
     QDepartment initalizedRoot = new QDepartment(root)
     // or
     QDepartment initalizedRoot = new QDepartment(root.getMetadata(),  PathInits.getFor(root.getMetadata(), new PathInits("*.*", "project.customer.company")));

    // use initializedRoot.project.customer.company
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using the QDepartment.project.customer.company.eq(idCompany) on the Service and the repository is called after that (so I get null pointer exception because the Path is not configured yet)

Comment: Is there any Annotation that I could use on my class to force PathInits INITS = {"*.*",   "project.customer.company"}?

When I dont have QueryInit, the PathInit INITS = "*.*", but when I add the QueryInit, it turns to {"*", "project.customer.company"} (with single *, not *.*)

Comment: Hmm hard to see whats going on, I'd actually expect the path to be initialized here. Can you try `@PathInits({"*". "*.*", "*.*.*", "*.*.*.*", "*.*.*.*.*"})`?

Comment: is `@PathInits` a annotation? Could not find

Comment: com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.PathInits, its a class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223056/discussion-between-renan-ceratto-and-jan-willem-gmelig-meyling).